# Reverse no invierte el array cuando lo uso referenciado a otra variable

Tags: javascript, lógica, javascript-metodo

Como pueden ver en el título, así de simple, cuando uso reverse en una variable que sale de convertir un número a string y luego a array entonces no funciona.

Esta función es para saber si un número es palindromo. Pueden usar 48921984 para probar, les debe devolver falso

```
function luckyNumber(value) {
  let valueArr = String(value).split('')
  let valueRev = valueArr.reverse() // De esta forma no se invierte el array
  // let valueRev = String(value).split('').reverse() -- Pero de esta si

  for (let i = 0; i <= Math.ceil(valueArr.length / 2); i++) {
    if (valueArr[i] != valueRev[i]) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Al final logré resolver el problema usando otro método como pueden ver, pero si alguien sabe que pasó ahí por favor que me ayude, investigué por mi cuenta y no di con la explicación.

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento de reverse destruye tu primer array, lo cual hace que valueArr cambie y tome el valor invertido al igual que valueRev.

```js
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
console.log('array1:', array1);
// output: "array1:" Array ["one", "two", "three"]

const reversed = array1.reverse();
console.log('reversed:', reversed);
// output: "reversed:" Array ["three", "two", "one"]

// reverse cambia el array original
console.log('array1:', array1);
// output: "array1:" Array ["three", "two", "one"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo he probado y de las 2 maneras me invierte el array. Eso sí, deberías poner en lugar de `valuerArr.reverse()`, `[...valueArr].reverse()`